# Error Class App\Repositories\Messages does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy intentando crear un repositorio para mis consultas pero me dice que la clase no existe.

Les muestro los fragmentos de código para ver si alguien sabe cuál es el error:

**MessagesControler.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Message;
use App\Repositories\Messages;
use App\Events\MessageWasRecived;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use App\Http\Requests\CreateMessageRequest;

class MessagesController extends Controller
{
    protected $messeges;
    function __construct(Messages $messeges)
    {
        $this->middleware('auth',['except' => ['create','store']]);
        $this->messeges = $messeges;
    }
```

Ruta de mi repositorio `app/Repositories/Messages.php`

**Messages.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Message;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;


class Messages 
{
    public function index()
    {
         $key = 'message.page' . request('page', 1);
            return = Cache::tags('messages')->rememberForever($key, function() {
                return Message::with(['user','note','tags'])
                                ->orderBy('created_at', request('sorted','ASC'))
                                ->paginate(10); 
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: El namespace debería ser `App\Repositories` y no `App\Repositories\Messages`, en caso contrario tu clase será `App\Repositories\Messages\Messages`, debiendo usar `use App\Repositories\Messages\Messages` en su lugar. Prueba el cambio y dime el resultado.

Comment: perdon lo tenia como tu dices y no me salia  pero quise probar así y se me olvido cambiar el archivo antes de subirlo

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un problema con los [espacios de nombre](http://php.net/language.namespaces) en tu proyecto.

Por un lado estás tratando de hacer uso de la clase `App\Repositories\Messages`, pero por otro lado has definido la clase `App\Repositories\Messages\Messages` (`namespace App\Repositories\Messages` + `class Messages`), por lo que no existe coincidencia entre ambos.

Debes recordar que en `use` debes introducir el espacio de nombres al que pertenece una clase más el nombre de ésta.

Puedes solucionarlo de dos formas:

**Usando la clase correcta:**

Puedes dejar intacto tu archivo `Messages.php` y hacer esta modificación en tu archivo `MessagesControler.php`:

```
<?php
/* ... */
use App\Message;
/* Agrego correctamente el nombre de la clase al espacio de nombres */
use App\Repositories\Messages\Messages;
use App\Events\MessageWasRecived;
/* ... */
```

**Corrigiendo el espacio de nombres:**

Puedes dejar intacto el archivo `MessagesControler.php` y hacer esta modificación en el archivo `Messages.php`:

```
<?php
/* Corregimos el espacio de nombres para no repetir nombre */
namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Message;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
/* ... */
```

Comment: he corregido, pero sigue sin funcionar nota: edite la pregunta para que ves como tengo los archivos ahora me parece que tengo el uso correcto de los namespace

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir tu `main.php` de configuración y el `composer.json`?

Comment: Antes de eso, te comento estoy utilizando Homestead así que decidí probar en otro proyecto que tenia de forma local y utilizando la misma lógica y sintaxis en el proyecto local funciono perfectamente, a que crees que se deba

Comment: Puede ser que el `conposer.json` no indique las rutas correctas o por algún motivo el autoloader no esté teniendo en cuenta esas rutas. No busques el archivo `main.php`, es de **yii**, otro framework diferente, me confundí al ponértelo.

Comment: ok veré lo del autoloder a lo mejor no esta mapeando la clase

Comment: ¿Conseguiste avanzar en este problema?

Comment: Sí lo solucione, al final era un problema con las clases

Comment: Te agradecería que crearas una respuesta con una descripción de cómo arreglaste el problema (y la marqués como respuesta correcta) para que otros visitantes puedan beneficiarse de ese conocimiento. Yo mismo te daré el primer voto positivo.